# QGIS 3.4.4 sorts numerical values as text, solution?

Tags: qgis-3, sorting

I'm trying to sort my numerical values in my attribute table but instead of getting 1, 2, 3 I get 1, 10, 100, 100 etc. When searching for a solution here on Stack Exchange, many people with earlier versions just had to update to a later one, 2.18 e.g. However, I still have this problem for my 3.4.4 version. How can I solve this bug?

Comment: where did your data come from?

Comment: What is the field type of the field containing the values?

Comment: @IanTurton It's from the Swedish Land Surveying Agency's open data on the road network

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the field's data type is Text. So it's sorting the numbers alphabetically.

Create a new field and populate it using the field calculator with

```
to_int("Your_Field")
```

The new field should sort numerically.

Bear in mind that this will only work for features which do not have any actually text characters in them.

Comment: You dont need to create a new field or even a virtual field, just right click on the a column header and choose "sort..." and you will access a calculator where you can enter the formula for sorting (in this case : to_int("Your_Field") ) strangely this formula work even if some feature have text character but the non numerical  didn't seem to be sorted (the purely numerical get sorted at top or bottom depending in sort order)